# Find a Basis for the $ \mathbb{Z}$ -module $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ containing $(3,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, modules

I suspect that this is an application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, or at least related to it. Also the theorem $\forall s, t \in\mathbb{Z} \hspace{2.5mm}, \forall z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \hspace{2.5mm} \exists c \in \mathbb{Z}, sz_1 + tz_2 = c\cdot \gcd(z_1,z_2)$ looks related.

But I can't figure out how to put this together.

Comment: There's something wrong with the statement of the "theorem": $d$ is the $\gcd(z_1,z_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to be able to express $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ as linear combinations of $(3,5)$ and some other $(x,y)$, where all the coefficients are integral.

That is for some $a,b,c,d$ we need
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
0 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\
c &d\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 &5 \\
x &y\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since the determinant of the left-hand side is $1$, and everything is integral the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}
3 &5 \\
x &y\\
\end{pmatrix}$ is $\pm 1$.

It's not hard to see that $(x,y)=(1,2)$ is a good choice.

The existence of $a,b,c,d$ is now automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The vectors $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ are a basis for $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ precisely when $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of them can produce the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (Do you see why?). Now can you guess some vectors and see how to check this criterion for your problem.

Hint': Determinants are pretty cool.

Comment: So $(1,0),(0,1)$ could be considered the standard basis for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  If I find two vectors generating those, those two are also a basis. Is there a method (like gaussian elimination) that I can use?

Comment: Not exactly like Gaussian elimination but CRT helps. Pick another vector to pair up with your $(3,5)$ and write out your equations to generate $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Now use CRT.

Comment: Okay, I have been trying out solving an integer based system of equations, but I'm not getting anywhere. Do I maybe need more than two vectors? Help!